# JMeter test cannot start on the TFS agent

Tags: java, tfs, jmeter

I'm trying to run the JMeter test using the TFS build definition. I've created the required task to run the JMeter test (command-line task), but I'm getting the following error:

```
Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.
errorlevel=2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I've checked the java version on the agent:

[image: I've checked the java version on the agent:]

I've mentioned the following system variables:

- `JMETER_HOME` as `C:\Performance Tests\apache-jmeter-3.2`
- `JRE_HOME` as `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231"`
- to the `Path` variable was added `C:\Performance Tests\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin`

When I try to run the JMeter on the agents I don't get any error:
[image]

Windows Server 2012 R2 64 bit is installed on the agent.

On another agent (which is the same and has similar configs) the test is running with no issues.

Could someone tell me what is the reason for the issue? Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have jdk (not jre) folder in C:\Program Files\Java\?

Comment: @user7294900 No, just jre

Comment: This is the issue, Find jdk folder or you need to reinstall java

Comment: I noticed that System capabilities in TFS for this agent does not contain java variables (like java_home, etc.). Could that be the reason for the issue?

Comment: When you install java you should choose jdk folder and use it as JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [jmeter.bat source](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/bin/jmeter.bat#L92):

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (
    rem @echo Debug Output: %%g
    set JAVAVER=%%g
)
if not defined JAVAVER (
    @echo Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.
    set ERRORLEVEL=2
    goto pause
)
```

it appears that the JMeter startup script is not capable of parsing the output of `java -version` command in order to determine Java runtime version

So make sure to have "bin" folder of your JRE or JDK installation added to your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable

In order to have 100% confidence that it will work add this line to the beginning of your *jmeter.bat* script:

```
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin";%PATH%
```

also be aware that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity

Comment: jmeter.bat editing helped to run JMeter test, thank you! afaik, TFS does not support JMeter after 3.2.

Comment: Now I have another issue: I have a command line task: `java -jar "C:/Performance Tests/SaxonHE9-9-1-5J/saxon9he.jar" -s:"C:\Performance Tests\Script\results\Result.xml" -xsl:"C:\Performance Tests\JMeter\xslt\jm.xsl" -o:"C:\Performance Tests\Script\results\JMeterJunitReport.xml"`, and I get the following error message here:` 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: The solution will be the same

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? Where the Path variable should be listed? in `saxon9he.jar`?